# How do I click to select more than one face a a time?

Tags: faces, selection-tools

I went into face select mode and it will not let me keep the faces as I select more and more. In other words, it only lets me select one face at a time. How can I make it so I can select multiple faces at a time and make the edit I need?

Comment: You seem to be quite new to Blender, judging by your previous questions. Might be worth your while starting by watching some beginner tutorials first, before diving into more complex tasks

Comment: Like most other software out there, holding the shift key while selecting will allow you to select multiple items.

Comment: try also other interactive selection tools: B then mouse drag (box select), C then mouse drag (circle select), ctrl-mousedrag (lazo)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just hold the <kbd>Shift</kbd> key while selecting, easy as that.